# Dynamics CRM Online 2016 - roll up field not calculating accurately in a custom entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

*Dynamics CRM 2016 Online.*

It seems that the rollup field is not calculating accurately (please see picture).

I have 2 custom entities - Menu, Recipe which has 1:N relationship

Am I missing something here?

[Rollup (field) VS actual(on a subgrid)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4nIn.png)

[Rollup field setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n6Vk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rollup fields are calculated by a scheduled system job that runs periodically in the background.  So, the rollup value that you see on the menu record (91.80) can be different from the calculation you have in the rollup field's definition if any of the recipe values have changed since the last time the rolled up value on the menu record last was calculated.

On the menu record, hover over the 91.80.  You will see a tooltip that tells you when the current value was last calculated, and you will also see a little refresh icon appear that allows you to force the calculation to refresh.  When you click the refresh icon, does the value correctly update?

Comment: Perfect. Forcing the refresh helped because "..the values have changed since the last time the rolled up value on the menu record last was calculated". Thanks @Polshgiant